# How to call a windows program in mysql prompt in windows

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

I want to call an OS level commands from mysql prompt within Windows command line tool.

In Unix* there is a system command available to execute OS commands within MySQL prompt.

Any way of dong the same in windows or even in workbench as well?

The objective is to invoke a OS command within a mysql prompt.

Comment: The posted answer (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86271/877) is the only plausible answer. Otherwise, the only workaround is ot get the source code for the mysql client and mysql workbench and inject `system` code into it.

Answer (score 1):

<del>You cannot run OS commands in a MySQL CLI nor in MySQL Workbench. Why would you do that (except for trying to hack a machine via an SQL connection)?</del> If you need to run an OS command, open a normal shell window (that still stands).

**Update:**
The system command only works on Unix like OSes (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html), e.g. Linux + Mac.

MySQL Workbench doesn't support most of these CLI commands however (`use` and `delimiter` are 2 that *are* supported).

Comment: what could i do if i need to call a OS command within procedure execution..

Comment: You simply can't. It's not allowed, certainly for security reasons.

Comment: if so then why it is allowed in UNIX* OS?..

Comment: I think with "*that stands still*" you actually mean "*that still stands*". "That stands still" means "it's not moving"...

Comment: any workaround to achieve the goal @a_horse_with_no_name  ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: :-D you should have read that as "that stands, still", but I guess it's not good english anyway. So, I changed as you suggested.

Comment: I would have upvoted this, but I am out of votes for today. Otherwise, this should be the accepted answer.